# using FineUploadBasic instead of fineUploader with Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, fine-uploader

I am using the fineuploader control with knockout.js via custom bindings.

Here is my code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.contractuploader = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            $(element).fineUploader({
                request: {
                    endpoint: '/UploadContract/UploadFile/',
                    params: valueAccessor(),
                    validation: {
                        allowedExtensions: ['doc', 'docx', 'pdf']
                    },
                    callbacks: {
                        onSuccess: function () {

                        },
                        onError: function (id, name, reason, xhr) {
                            toastr.error(reason);
                        }
                    }
                },
                button: $(".my-custom-class")
            }).on('complete', function (event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                if (responseJSON.success) {

                }
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
            // and again whenever the associated observable changes value.
            // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
        }
    };
```

I notice in the jquery.fineuploader-4.2.1.js

```
$.fn.fineUploader = function(optionsOrCommand) {

}
```

but I want to use the basic function so that I point it to anchor like this:

```
<div class="upload-button-div">
   <a data-bind="contractuploader : { 'jobId': JobId }">Upload a File</a>
</div>
```

I don't want all extra features that come with the control. Just a link that opens the file selection window and then upload the file to endpoint.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I think the question is - How do I use the basic version and use an anchor tag as mentioned.